# How to parse .eml file in java and extract information?

Tags: java, email

```java
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.host", "smtp.dummydomain.com");
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp"); 
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,null); 
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session, responseInputStream);
LOGGER.info("Subject : {} ",message.getContent());
```

I have tried with above code ,but subject is `null`. Any idea ?

Comment: What is `responseInputStream` defined as?

Comment: Are you trying to send (hence the properties) or to parse an existing email, like your title says? You may want to read [ask] and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: responseInputStream  is InputStream returned from body of  .eml file

Comment: @rober i just want to parse from InputStream to extract informations like header ,body,recipients ,reply-to etc.